# PHP Form that Creates SQL Table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP Form that pushes information to a PHP script that adds information to a SQL database, I want to create an event that will create a New Table as well. This is my current code

```
 $sql = "CREATE TABLE ".$ac_system." (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , PRIMARY KEY 
 (id) , account_nr CHAR(10) , credits CHAR(10))";    //Edited This Section from VAR to CHAR
 if (mysql_query($sql, $con)) {
            $insertSuccessful = true;
        } else {
            echo $sql;
            print_r($_POST);
            echo "\n" . mysql_error($con);
            echo "mysql err no : " . mysql_errno($con);
        }
        $sql1 = "insert into etrack_clients set     
        ac_name = '".$ac_name."',
        ac_ck = '".$ac_ck."',
        ac_ckdoc2 = '".$ac_ckdoc2."'" ;

    if (mysql_query($sql1, $con)) {
            $insertSuccessful = true;
        } else {
            echo $sql1;
            print_r($_POST);
            echo "\n" . mysql_error($con);
            echo "mysql err no : " . mysql_errno($con);
```

The SQL1 works fine on its own but as soon as I add the SQL first one it stops to work and this is the error I get

```
 CREATE TABLE TREVOR123 (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , PRIMARY KEY (id) , account_nr 
 VAR(10) , credits VAR(10))Array ( [ac_name] => Test [ac_psira] => Test [ac_ck] => Test 
 [ac_system] => TREVOR123 [ac_contactp] => Test [ac_contnr] => Test [ac_fax] => 
 [ac_email] => [ac_date] => [ac_account] => Prepaid [ac_payment] => COD 
 [ac_paymentdate] => [ac_notes] => [submit] => Submit ) You have an error in your SQL 
 syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
 syntax to use near 'VAR(10) , credits VAR(10))' at line 1mysql err no : 1064
```

I just need to create the table the table will be populated from another screen

Comment: Creating tables on the fly is usually a bad idea.  Normalized databases work well in most instances.  If you don't know what that means, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Comment: I understand what you saying but the previous developer on this site has created a table for each client loaded, I tried making it easier on myself by continueing with this but looks like more headaches rather have one Table and just filter the the queries. This unluckly will have me re-writing most of the site

Comment: I have changed VAR to CHAR and it accepts and creates the Table now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`VAR` doesn't exist. `VARCHAR` and `CHAR` *do* exist.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-types.html)

Answer (score 0):

change this line:

```
VAR(10) , credits VAR(10))Array ( [ac_name] => Test [ac_psira] => Test [ac_ck] => Test
```

to:

```
VARCHAR(10) , credits VARCHAR(10))Array ( [ac_name] => Test [ac_psira] => Test [ac_ck] => Test
```

**You can find a list of MySQL data types here:**

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-type-overview.html